# vhs vimeo ViewHelper

Tags: fluid, typo3-7.6.x

on my Site the User can insert a Vimeo URL, something like this:
https://vimeo.com/181873015
I want to extract only the last Part:
181873015
cause this is the one i need for the v:media.vimeo ViewHelper. So i thought i could do it like this:

```
<v:format.replace substring="https://vimeo.com/" content="{data.tx_extend_ttcontent_vimeo}" replacement="''" count="1">
</v:format.replace>
```

But i don`t know how the get the Result. Something like this:

```
<v:format.replace substring="https://vimeo.com/" content="{data.vimeo}" replacement="''" count="1" as="videoID">
</v:format.replace>
```

Does not work.

Then i thought maybe the inline Notation is the right one. So i tried this:

```
<v:media.vimeo videoId="{v:format.replace(substring: \'https://vimeo.com/\', content: \'{data.tx_extend_ttcontent_vimeo}\', replacement: '\'\'', count: 1)}" width="123" height="123" title="1" byline="1" portrait="1" color="'00adef'" autoplay="1" loop="1" api="1" playerId="NULL">
        </v:media.vimeo>
```

The Result is:

```
<iframe src="//player.vimeo.com/video/{v:format.replace(substring: \'https://vimeo.com/\', content: \' https://vimeo.com/181873015\', replacement: '\'\'', count: 1)}?title=1&byline=1&portrait=1&color='00adef'&autoplay=1&loop=1&api=1&player_id=NULL" webkitallowfullscreen="webkitAllowFullScreen" mozallowfullscreen="mozAllowFullScreen" allowfullscreen="allowFullScreen" width="123" height="123" frameborder="0">
```

So does anyone know what is the right inline Notation or how can i use the Tag Version???

Thanks

Bernd

Comment: ah i didn`t realize that <v:format.replace> search inside the Tag for the substring and replace it. So correct is this:<v:format.replace substring="https://vimeo.com/" replacement="" count="1">
 <v:media.vimeo videoId="{data.tx_extend_ttcontent_vimeo}" title="1" byline="1" portrait="1" color="'00adef'" autoplay="0" loop="0" api="1" playerId="vimeoplayer"></v:media.vimeo>
</v:format.replace>.